# AS3 Library to read and draw GIS data (shp file)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dictionary, gis

I'm working on an app that should display GIS data.
I had previous experience on this kind of dataset in Processing, and I'm looking for a good AS3 library to help me out.

Right now I'm testing Edwin van Rijkom’s library (shp and dfp libraries [here](http://code.google.com/p/vanrijkom-flashlibs/)), following some good tutorials I've found [here](http://vis4.net/blog/posts/reading-shapefiles-in-as3/).

Do you know if there is any good alternative?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'm going to reply myself if someone would need it.

I've found [this](http://andywoodruff.com/blog/simple-shapefile-drawing-in-actionscript-3/) library by Andy Woodruff, it's basically a wrapper of Edwin van Rijkom’s libraries, but it makes easier to work with data

Hope it helps!